# asp mvc@Scripts.Render in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, area

I have one area in my asp mvc5 application

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl0UO.png)

Nothing happens when I use  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin/site")` in layoutpage 
But when I use `@Styles.Render("~/bookkeeping/Content/site")`, it works fine 
both Render (Styles & Scripts) in same layout page.

adminAreaRegistration class is inside admin area

```
public class adminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{

    public override string AreaName
    {

        get
        {

            return "admin";
        }
    }
    private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        if (bundles == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("bundles"); }

        // Bookings Bundles
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/admin/site")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
            "~/Areas/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bookkeeping/Content/site")
            .Include("~/Areas/admin/Content/Site.css",
            "~/Areas/admin/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Areas/admin/Content/adminstyles.css"));

        // Account Overview Bundle

    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        context.MapRoute(
            "admin_default",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```